# Translucent windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

The look I'm going for is like 
[image: Attempt] where the sidebar is semi-transparent and the background can be seen through. However `TransparencyKey` only takes into account the pixels at the top, if there is another panel on top that means that together they do not fit the transparency key then it will be opaque.

I have the TransparencyKey set to Fuchsia and the grapefruit sidebar is on top and is changed to `sidebar.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128,255,255,255);` on load.

[image: Attempt]

As you see the TransparencyKey only works on the top.
I have also tried setting the transparency on the form with undesired results.

**How would I go about making the sidebar translucent?**

[**Solution v**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943628/translucent-windows-form#answer-38943932)

Comment: WPF looks like your best bet

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you, WPF works perfectly.

Comment: If WPF works for: FINE! In winforms the next best thing would have been a slightly reduced opacity.

Comment: Layered windows support both top-level and child windows as of Windows 8, so this should be entirely possible in WinForms. I haven't played around with it myself. Glassy transparency went out of style with Aero in Windows 7. You are using a non-standard theme for your operating system; don't expect users to prefer your app to behave in the same non-standard way.

Comment: Since you can accept your own answer after 48 hours, you don't need to put a link to answer in your question. Also Instead of `v` you can use `↓` or `▼` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't do that in winforms.  Period.  It's an antiquated technology that doesn't support "real" transparency.  Whenever you see the word "transparent", it really means your control will inherit the back color of its parent.  It does not mean you can see things that are behind it.

You *may* be able to do it with WPF, though I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thank you, I had suspicions about that after trying, thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: WPF is the solution, ` WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"` on the window.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @JeremyThompson WPF is absolutely fine at doing this.

Inside the window include `WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"` and then use panels/canvases as normal.

[image: Working form!]